# Oracle create table not working when executed from SQL Script

Tags: oracle

I have a create table statement on a Oracle Script file and when I executed the script file, I am unable to create the table.

Content of script file

```
-- Table Creation Script

CREATE TABLE SampleTable
(

FIELD1 NUMBER NOT NULL,
FIELD2 DATE NULL,
FIELD3 DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
FIELD4 DATE NULL,
FIELD5 NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 1,
FIELD5 NUMBER(10) NULL,
FIELD6 VARCHAR2(1000) NULL
);
```

I am getting a SP2-0734: error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

One - remove that carriage return between ( and FIELD1

Two - there are two FIELD5 entries, giving the result ORA-00957: duplicate column name

Here:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable
(
FIELD1 NUMBER NOT NULL,
FIELD2 DATE NULL,
FIELD3 DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
FIELD4 DATE NULL,
FIELD5 NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 1,
FIELD6 NUMBER(10) NULL,
FIELD7 VARCHAR2(1000) NULL
);
```

Comment: The carriage return was the problem. I mistyped the question with two field5. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has several promising answers that may resolve your problem.

http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2010/01/sp2-0734-unknown-command-beginning-rest.html